# How far can a branch instruction jump in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am kinda confused right now. How far can a branch instruction in MIPS jump?
I actually found a answer, which says +/-128 kByte, which would be 2^21 bit, if I'm not wrong. But I just don't get how this can be. On the sheet we were given at university is written that beq an bne are calculated this way PC = PC+4+BranchAddress. And the BrachAddress itself is {14{immediate[15]}, immediate, 2'b0}, which if I'm not wrong means, that there is a 16 bit immediate, where the MSB is extended by 14 "places" to the left and on the right it gets extended by 2 zeros. So wouldn't this mean that the Branchaddress has to be 2^18 bit ?

Answer (score 2):

You should check an instruction set reference like [this](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/1/16/MIPS32_Architecture_Volume_II-A_Instruction_Set.pdf). You can see that BEQ instruction for example is encoded as

```
------------------------------------------------------
| 6 bit opcode | 5 bit rs | 5 bit rt | 16 bit offset |
------------------------------------------------------
```

And regarding offset it states:

> An 18-bit signed offset (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address of the instruction following
>   the branch (not the branch itself), in the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address

This means that the 16 bit value is left shifted by 2 (multiplied by 4, which basically aligns it to a double word) and interpreted as a signed number. This yields a value in range `[-2^17, 2^17 - 1]` so `[-131072, 131071]`. But you must take into account that the value is added to the instruction after the branch so the actual range relative to the instruction itself is `[-131072+4, 131071+4]`.

The story is different for unconditional jump `BC` which has 26 bits for the offset (which are still shifted to the left by 2), so a 28 bit signed number.